# Write that in CPP class file

Tags: visual-c++, object-oriented-analysis

```
   bool guess( string aNumberString );
```

i got this in header file in x.h but how do you define that in the class .

I don't know How to do that !!

By the way I am using c++ !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool x::guess(string aNumberString) 
{
 // Defination
};
```